# Visual Studio Pro 2019 16.8.4 - Script Task Editor Not Opening in SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, vsta

Setup: Visual Studio Pro 2019 16.8.4, SSIS installed. When I try to access Script Editor Window and update C# code, it does nothing. Never opens nor does it give me an error, it is unresponsive. - Someone else reported this to Microsoft, but there is no real answer yet (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1308953/unable-to-repair-visual-studio-tools-for-applicati.html)

I have tried running vsta_setup.exe from Control Panel, but when it tries to repair I get a warning message that it can not locate the latest vsta_setup.exe in C:\ drive. Microsoft's latest vsta_setup file is actually not compatible with VS 2019 16.8.4.

I've tried repairing VS 2019 from installer and I still can not open Script Task Editor when working with SSIS Packages. I'm puzzled why the latest VS Pro 2019 version doesn't have the necessary repair tools to help troubleshoot and fix this issue.

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74530949/2058808

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to solve it, hopefully it helps you. My answer is also posted on Microsoft Community link and it contains the **latest vsta_setup.exe version 16.0.29425** (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1308953/unable-to-repair-visual-studio-tools-for-applicati.html)

I have Visual Studio Pro 2019 16.8.4 and VSTA from Script Task Editor would not open, unresponsive, no error message. I tried repairing Visual Studio; Repairing Data Tools for SSIS; and even tried repairing VSTA from Control Panel but none of that worked. The one error I did get from trying to repair VSTA from control panel, was the the vsta_setup.exe was not available or outdated. ** The solution in order to get the latest vsta_setup.exe** for me was opening up Windows Explorer going into C:\ drive and searched for "vsta_setup.exe" took a while. Several options came up, I hovered on each vsta_setup.exe and finally found the set up file matching what control panel had for Visual Studio 2019; "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019 version 16.0.29425". I copied the file I found through the search and ran set up a couple times and it's now working