# SSIS - Nothing happens when clicking on "Edit Script" button

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2017. SSIS and SSRS worked fine until yesterday.

But now, when I click on SSIS "Edit Script" button, nothing happens.

I have uninstalled SSDT and re-installed, but I am still having the problem.

Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll exists on these folders:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Tasks (and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks)
2. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Tasks (and C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks)
3. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 (and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91)

Why out of a sudden the "Edit Script" button does not work, and how can I fix this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

This answer worked !
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/659573/ssis-2017-nothing-happens-when-clicking-on-34edit.html?childToView=659692#answer-659692

SSIS Script Task is using "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications".
If you cannot open Script Task editor, it means there is an issue with it.

Please go to Control Panel, find there "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017".
Right mouse click, Change, Repair.

Comment: This solution also worked for Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019. The repair actually downloaded and reinstalled this component.

Comment: Wow, such a relief that I don't have to re-install. What a pain! Glad this one worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug introduced to Visual Studio 2019 and its SSIS extension.
It has been resolved.

**Uninstall current versions.**

**Install updated versions:**

- [**Download Visual Studio 2019 v.16.10.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.10)

  - [Download SQL Server Integration Services Projects v.3.14.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

Comment: Thank you. But, I am using Visual Studio (and SSIS) 2017. Is there a solution for version 2017 ?

Comment: You're welcome, sadly there isnt currently.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties, and make sure right TargetServerVersion is set. It was set to SQL Server 2019 in my case, but I didn't have this version installed on my local computer. Since I only have SQL Server 2017 installed on my local computer, changing it to SQL Server 2017 solved my problem.

[image]